# How to display tab bar in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have created tabbar based project in MT and I have following flow in my storyboard;

```
Tabbarcontroller -> 1) MainViewController -> CustomerViewController;
                    2) SettingViewController
```

The problem I am having is that when I use `PrepareForSegue` function in `CustomerViewController` and pointing it to `MainViewController`. Tab Bar UI is missing from `MainViewController`.

I know that if I point to `TabBarController` it is going to be fine. But I need to pass some data exactly to `MainViewController`.

Is there any way to make it. I am new in iOS and monotouch. Any suggestion appreciate.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with *Tab Bar UI is missing from MainViewController* and *I know that if I point to TabBarController it is going to be fine. But I need to pass some data exactly to MainViewController*? Could you expand on those? It's not clear for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted it is Ok. I already solved this issue. But anyway thank you

Comment: If possible, answer your question and then mark it as answred. In this way other people can see a solution if they have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Strange ... this question helped me to find the answer of my problem.